# Number of distinct prime ideals in $\mathbb {Q}[x]/\langle x^m-1 \rangle$

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, ideals, maximal-and-prime-ideals

Number of prime ideals in quotient ring obtained by  $\mathbb {Q}[x]/\langle x^m-1 \rangle$ is ...?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The ideals of $\mathbb Q[x]/(x^m-1)$ correspond to the ideals of $\mathbb Q[x]$ that contain $(x^m-1)$ and these are the ideals generated by the divisors of $x^m-1$.

So the question is reduced to finding the prime decomposition of $x^m-1$. The answer is
$$x^m - 1 = \prod_{d\mid m} \Phi_d(x)$$
where $\Phi_n(x)$ is the [$n$-th cyclotomic polynomial](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cyclotomic_polynomial). It is true but not trivial that $\Phi_n(x)$ is irreducible.

Therefore, the number of prime ideals of $\mathbb Q[x]/(x^m-1)$ is the number of divisors of $m$.

Comment: How do you get expression for decomposition?

Comment: @lowiq, by grouping primitive roots of unity of the same order.

Comment: why are ideals containing x^m-1 prime in Q[x]/x^m-1

Comment: @lowiq, because of the [ring isomorphisms theorems](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Isomorphism_theorem#Rings)